# Warning Message when room is Booked and not deleting every day

Tags: exchange, calendar

So my problem is, my boss asked me if it is possible for when they try to schedule a meeting on outlook and the room that they are trying to schedule a meeting for x days on x hours and if in one of that days there is another meeting on that hour it cancels all the scheduled days instead of only the day that conflicts.

Is it possible to leave the other that don't have conflict to stay booked instead of being deleted and expel some warning message to the person that is trying to schedule the meeting that, that day is booked and it needs to schedule to another day?

Thanks you all that help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the PS commandlet `Set-CalendarProcessing`. The parameters are `MaximumConflictInstances` and `ConflictPercentageAllowed`. These values determine how many conflicts are allowed when creating a reccuring appointment before the booking is refused completely.

For example, if you set `MaximumConflictInstances` to 5, you create a weekly appointment for 1 year (52 instances): if there are 5 or less conflicts, all possible appointments are booked in this room, but the 5 conflicts are not booked and you get an email message from the server with the dates that could not be reserved. If you have more than 5 conflicts, the meeting will be refused completely.

As far as I know, if you set both values, the first threshold that is exceeded will count.

Comment: I tried to do with the Set-CalendarProcessing and with Set-MailboxCalendarSettings and both say that they are not recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program.

Comment: It is an exchange commandlet, so you habe to Run it Insider the Ecxhange PS Console - and you need at least Exchange 2010 as far as I know.

Comment: After some time i got it working with MaximumConflictInstances.

Thank you Tobias!